# Apply Image as Texture / Material and cut to fit shape

Tags: texturing, image

Im a Fusion 360 user, and am learning blender as a program to be able to export finalized models in a format accepted by AR programs (one of Fusions big shortcomings). Im currently modelling snowboards for AR storefronts.

The board is a finalized state in Fusion but the decals (topsheet graphic and base graphic) are lost on export to fbx.  As below
[image]

Ive tried in blender to add the image as a texture with an image shader, and the image just trys to wrap itself around the sides of the board and doesn't behave like I want. Not very experienced at all at blender so I am more than likely doing something wrong.

Closest Ive got is to apply the image as a plane and add a shrinkwrap modifier which gets the result below. The problem I think is the image I am trying to apply as the top sheet graphic is a rectangular jpeg which in Fusion and photoshop you can just place over the board shape and trim it to shape. Is there a way to do this in blender or should I be trying a different software?
The topsheet graphic really needs to be exact in its placement and reflection of what the physical snowboards look like

[image]

Comment: You need to UV unwrap your model. [Royal Skies tutorial on unwrapping] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cS6B5PAzlWI) is a good source